# Using PHP to call JS to change HTML table cell values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to manipulate my HTML table using datavalues from an SQL database that I'm extracting using PHP.

I've tried a tonne of different ways but I think the best way would be how I am approaching it now, by using a loop to assign an ID tag number corresponding to the Matrix Value of that array.

(EXAMPLE: 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23 etc..)

I am then calling a JavaScript function to find the element with that particular ID and replace the value with the SQL Data taken out by the PHP code.

I've inspected the elements on Chrome and can see the data going into the function but the values within the table are staying blank and not being set to the values from the mySQL.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE 1"; 
    $tableHeader = "<body><center><div><table id=\"infoTable\" class=\"myTable \"><tr><th></th><th> 1 </th><th> 2 </th><th> 3 </th></tr>";  
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 


    //To Table Details

    //prints StackerReclaimer_StatusTable;
    include("SR_TableStatus.php");
    // output data of each row
    echo $tableHeader;
    for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++){ //Rows
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query);
        if($i == 2 || $i==4)
            echo"<tr><td> </td></tr>";
        echo"<tr><td class = \"leftCol\"> Bed ".($i)."</td>";

        for ($j=1;$j<4;$j++){ //Cols
            echo"<td bgcolor=\"#E9E6E5\" id =\"$i$j\"></td>";
        /***************************************/
        $data = strtoupper($row["sortcode"])." (".(($row["stock"])/1000)."k)";
        if( $row["bednumber"] == $i && $row["pilenumber"] == $j ){
        //  echo"<td bgcolor=\"#E9E6E5\" id = $i$j>".strtoupper($row["sortcode"])." (".(($row["stock"])/1000)."k)</td>";
        echo "<script>swapValue($i$j, ".$data.");</script>";
        }
        /***************************************/                           
        }

    echo"</tr>";
    } 
    echo "</table></div></body></center>";      
?>
<!-- This script allows user to click on table rows to direct user to More info for that Coal -->
<script>

    function swapValue(var location, var data){
        var s = document.getElementById(location);
        s.value = data;
    }   

    var table = document.getElementById("infoTable");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                tableText(this);
                myFunc();
                };
        }
    }

    function tableText(tableCell) {
        //alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
        var Val = tableCell.innerHTML;
        Val = Val.substring(0,7);
        document.getElementById("searchBox").value = Val;
        document.getElementById("searchButton").click();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get the outcome needed.

After standing back and taking a break to rest the mind & Eyes, I've came back with fresh eyes and have now solved the issue, i was cluttering up the code by using javascript into the php which just adds to a mess if anyone was to decode or read.

so what the code does is reads values from an SQL database using PHP, reads the bednumber(Location(y)) and pileNumber(location(x))
it then makes the table using the for loops I for Rows and J for Columns,
then each column increment you need to update the SQL Query being sent back with the new cell location $i & $j which are held in the bed and pile number values.
i will post the code that now works, but any suggestions or corrections are gratefully appreciated.

```
<?php
    $tableHeader = "<body><center><div><table id=\"infoTable\" class=\"myTable \"><tr><th></th><th> 1 </th><th> 2 </th><th> 3 </th></tr>";  
    //prints StackerReclaimer_StatusTable;
    include("SR_TableStatus.php");
    // output data of each row
    echo $tableHeader;
        /*####################################*/
        for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
            //$row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query);
            if($i == 2 || $i==4)
                echo"<tr><td> </td></tr>";
            echo"<tr><td class = \"leftCol\"> Bed ".($i)."</td>";
            for ($j=1;$j<4;$j++){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE `bednumber` = $i AND `pilenumber` = $j";
            $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query);  //Creates a loop to loop through results
                if( $row["bednumber"] == $i && $row["pilenumber"] == $j ){
                    echo"<td bgcolor=\"#E9E6E5\">".strtoupper($row["sortcode"])." (".(($row["stock"])/1000)."k)</td>";
                }
                else 
                    echo"<td bgcolor=\"#E9E6E5\"> --- </td>";
            }
        echo"</tr>";
        } /*################################*/
    echo "</table></div></center></body>";  
?>
<!-- This script allows user to click on table rows to direct user to More info for that Coal -->

    <script>
        var table = document.getElementById("infoTable");
        if (table != null) {
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
                table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                    tableText(this);
                };
            }
        }

        function tableText(tableCell) {
            //alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
            var Val = tableCell.innerHTML;
            Val = Val.substring(0,7);
            document.getElementById("searchBox").value = Val;
            document.getElementById("searchButton").click();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> echo `"</table></div></body></center>"`

first you did not end the tag properly. you placed  out of body
second your  block is not even inside body block

so i suggest you rewrite like this

```
<body>
<div>
<table id="infoTable" class="myTable">
<tr><th></th><th> 1 </th><th> 2 </th><th> 3 </th></tr>
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE 1"; 
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 


    //To Table Details

    //prints StackerReclaimer_StatusTable;
    include("SR_TableStatus.php");
    // output data of each row

    for ($i=1;$i<5;$i++){ //Rows
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query);
        if($i == 2 || $i==4)
            echo"<tr><td> </td></tr>";
        echo"<tr><td class = \"leftCol\"> Bed ".($i)."</td>";

        for ($j=1;$j<4;$j++){ //Cols
            echo"<td bgcolor=\"#E9E6E5\" id =\"$i$j\"></td>";
        /***************************************/
        $data = strtoupper($row["sortcode"])." (".(($row["stock"])/1000)."k)";
        if( $row["bednumber"] == $i && $row["pilenumber"] == $j ){
        //  echo"<td bgcolor=\"#E9E6E5\" id = $i$j>".strtoupper($row["sortcode"])." (".(($row["stock"])/1000)."k)</td>";
        echo "<script>swapValue($i$j, ".$data.");</script>";
        }
        /***************************************/                           
        }

    echo"</tr>";
    } 

?>
 </table>
 </div>

    <!-- This script allows user to click on table rows to direct user to More info for that Coal -->
<script>

    function swapValue(var location, var data){
        var s = document.getElementById(location);
        s.value = data;
    }   

    var table = document.getElementById("infoTable");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                tableText(this);
                myFunc();
                };
        }
    }

    function tableText(tableCell) {
        //alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
        var Val = tableCell.innerHTML;
        Val = Val.substring(0,7);
        document.getElementById("searchBox").value = Val;
        document.getElementById("searchButton").click();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah I've never wrote html before, so my syntax is horrible I'm sure, but i appreciate the formatting thanks, any idea why the Cell Values aren't being inserted  by the JavaScript?

Comment: Aaron, your script is outside of body tag that 's why it is never executed. Look at the code i formatted above. you will see i placed your script block back to body block.

Comment: i had changed around the html blocks into proper order but the code still wasn't executing properly.
Instead, i fell back to a PHP version that has the safe outcome and found it was easier to read through the code.